# Drawing a continues line with onTouchMoved callback cocos2dx

Tags: c++, ios, opengl-es, cocos2d-x

i'm trying to draw a continues spline on every onTouchMoved call, 
the functionality is supposed to be similar to the line drawing used in the iOS game - flight control.

i'm using it in the following manner:

constructor init:

```
conPointsArray = new PointArray();
conPointsArray->initWithCapacity(DEF_ARRAY_SIZE);
lineDrawer = DrawNode::create();
```

the onTouchMoved callback usage:

```
void line::onTouchMoved(cocos2d::Touch *Touch, cocos2d::Event *Event)
{
conPointsArray->addControlPoint(Touch->getLocation());
lineDrawer->drawCardinalSpline((conPointsArray), 0.5f, 100, Color4F::BLUE);
CCLOG("on touch moved x: %f y %f", Touch->getLocation().x, Touch->getLocation().y);
}
```

But the app is always crashing in a certain openGL function.

I assumed the reason for it is because the array is constantly changing and openGL is having trouble with it (and the fact i'm always sending the same array which is a bad idea, but just to see how things work), so i moved the drawing call to onTouchEnded, And indeed, The line was drawn, but only (as expected) after the onTouch action has ended.

What is the solution/best practice for this issue?

**EDIT:**

This is the openGL function in which the code crashes:

```
void DrawNode::onDrawGLLine(const Mat4 &transform, uint32_t flags)
{
    auto glProgram = GLProgramCache::getInstance()->getGLProgram(GLProgram::SHADER_NAME_POSITION_LENGTH_TEXTURE_COLOR);
    glProgram->use();
    glProgram->setUniformsForBuiltins(transform);

    if (_dirtyGLLine)
    {
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _vboGLLine);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(V2F_C4B_T2F)*_bufferCapacityGLLine, _bufferGLLine, GL_STREAM_DRAW);
        _dirtyGLLine = false;
    }
    if (Configuration::getInstance()->supportsShareableVAO())
    {
        GL::bindVAO(_vaoGLLine);
    }
    else
    {
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _vboGLLine);
        GL::enableVertexAttribs(GL::VERTEX_ATTRIB_FLAG_POS_COLOR_TEX);
        // vertex
        glVertexAttribPointer(GLProgram::VERTEX_ATTRIB_POSITION, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(V2F_C4B_T2F), (GLvoid *)offsetof(V2F_C4B_T2F, vertices));
        // color
        glVertexAttribPointer(GLProgram::VERTEX_ATTRIB_COLOR, 4, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, GL_TRUE, sizeof(V2F_C4B_T2F), (GLvoid *)offsetof(V2F_C4B_T2F, colors));
        // texcood
        glVertexAttribPointer(GLProgram::VERTEX_ATTRIB_TEX_COORD, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(V2F_C4B_T2F), (GLvoid *)offsetof(V2F_C4B_T2F, texCoords));
    }
    glLineWidth(2);
    glDrawArrays(GL_LINES, 0, _bufferCountGLLine); <----------- CRASH HERE
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    CC_INCREMENT_GL_DRAWN_BATCHES_AND_VERTICES(1,_bufferCountGLLine);
    CHECK_GL_ERROR_DEBUG();
}
```

Comment: What was the openGL function it was crashing in?

Comment: Added the function...

Comment: I am not completely sure but it could be that you are using vbo's and not updating them with your vertex array update. Is _dirtyGLLine true for you? If not see how it can be set to true and if that solves your crash ?

Comment: @raveesh, it's a cocos2dx function which handles all the openGL stuff. didn't touch anything over there. just guessing it's supposed to work in a certain matter (which i'm still trying to figure out)

Comment: Yes, i got that. But there could be some other indirect way through which _dirtyGLLine is set to true, like some function in your draw node??. Sorry if this is is not helpful, but i actually  had a similar problem when working with openscenegraph and it got solved by setting a "dirty" flag on my drawable's vertex array; it ensured that even the VBO was internally updated.